# Static function in case class (Scala)

Tags: scala, static-methods, case-class

I have a case class in a Scala application, and a static function which I prefer to write within that class, as it makes the best sense.
This is the class:

```
case class At (
    date : DateTime,
    id : String,
    location : Coordinate
)
{
...

   def getParsedValues(line : String) : At =
   {
      val mappedFields : Array[String] = Utils.splitFields(line)
      val atObject = new At(mappedFields)
      return atObject;
   }

...
}
```

And then from another Scala object, I would like to call the method `getParsedValues()` as static method:

```
object Reader{
...
    var atObject = At.getParsedValues(line)
...
}
```

But it get an error `value getParsedEvent is not a member of object At`

How can I make it work? Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The standard way to write the equivalent of Java static methods in Scala is to add the method to the class's companion object. So:

```
case class At (
    date : DateTime,
    id : String,
    location : Coordinate
)

object At
{
...

   def getParsedValues(line : String) : At =
   {
      val mappedFields : Array[String] = Utils.splitFields(line)
      val atObject = new At(mappedFields)
      return atObject;
   }

...
}
```

Then call this as you already do in your `Reader` object.

Also, the constructor variant you will presumably need that takes an `Array[String]` might be better coded as a factory method in that same companion object. The middle line of your "static" method would then drop the `new` keyword. Also, you can drop the assignment to `atObject` and the `return atObject` line - the result of the last expression of a method is automatically taken as the return value for the method. Indeed, the whole method can be written as just:

```
def getParsedValues(line: String): At = At(Utils.splitFields(line))
```

Comment: The problem with this approach: If you declare a custom companion object for case classes the compiler won't add some utility methods, e.g. `tupled` is missing afterwards. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/25392422/935676

Comment: Fair point, @amoebe - perhaps a separate object, 'AtUtils' or the like, could be used where this is an issue.