# Case Class default apply method

Tags: scala, case-class

Assuming we have the following case class:

```
case class CasePerson(firstName: String)
```

And we also define a companion object for it:

```
object CasePerson {
 def apply() = new CasePerson( "XYZ" )
}
```

Notice that in the example above I explicitly defined a companion object with an `apply` method, without defining the the default apply method:

```
// This "default" apply has the same argument as the primary constructor of the case class
def apply(firstName : String) = new CasePerson(firstName)
```

**Q:** So where does Scala gets this "default" apply? I explicitly defined the companion object here without the default apply and the compiler still knows how to execute this:

```
val casePerson = CasePerson("PQR")
```

How does this work?

Answer (score 19):

Case classes are implicitly accompanied with a companion object with an `apply()` that has the same arguments as the primary constructor of the case class.

That is:

```
case class CasePerson(firstName: String)
```

Will  be accompanied by

```
object CasePerson{
   def apply(firstName: String) = new CasePerson(firstName)
}
```

Now if you also explicitly define a companion object, you can think of it as appending to the implicitly defined one.

For instance, in your example you added one new `apply` to the companion object:

```
object CasePerson{
   def apply() = new CasePerson("XYZ")
}
```

This statement, you can think of it as if it is creating an combined companion object:

```
object CasePerson{
   def apply() = new CasePerson("XYZ") // the one manually added
   def apply(firstName: String) = new CasePerson(firstName) // this one is automatically added
}
```

Now, if you decide to add your own version of the `apply` that has the same arguments as the primary constructor, then this will overshadow the default behavior of the case class.

```
object CasePerson{
   def apply() = new CasePerson("XYZ")
   def apply(s: String) = Seq(new CasePerson(s), new CasePerson(s)) // will replace the default factory for the case class
}
```

Now, if you call `CasePerson("hi")` it will instead generate:

```
List(CasePerson("hi"), CasePerson("hi"))
```

Comment: Replicating this, the 1st apply works, but the 2nd results in the error message:

ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method apply in object CasePerson of type (firstName: String)A$A28.this.CasePerson
and  method apply in object CasePerson of type (s: String)Seq[A$A28.this.CasePerson]
match argument types (String)

Comment: @Mark thanks for letting me know! Which Scala version did you use?Are you using a REPL? In case you are in a REPL make sure you use the `paste:` option so both you class and its companion object are defined together in a single block.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use just `= CasePerson(...)` instead of `= new CasePerson(...)` in the additional apply methods? (apart from the obvious case where you are overriding the default)

Answer (score 9):

Scala case classes are syntactic sugar. When you create a case class the Scala compiler will create a companion object with an `apply` and an `unapply` method for you, which you can then use as if it simply exists. [Here](http://www.alessandrolacava.com/blog/scala-case-classes-in-depth/) is a link to more in depth information on case classes.

Answer (score -1):

You may also give your `firstName` class parameter a default value. So you can create an instance with passing no parameter.

Example:

```
case class CasePerson(firstName : String = "XYZ")
val person = CasePerson()
```

Comment: My apologies for the down vote, but this is not what the question is asking.