# In Scala, how can an Inner case class consistently override a method?

Tags: scala, inheritance, overriding, case-class

I recently discovered that Scala compiler has an interesting feature for case class: Since it generates both a class & an object signature, if defined as an inner class, it can be used to override an abstract type definition and a function definition of its super class with minimal boilerplate code, here is an example:

```
object InnerCaseClassOverridingBoth {

  trait AALike

  trait SS {
    type AA <: AALike
    def AA(): AnyRef
  }

  trait SS_Clear extends SS {
    def AA(): AnyRef
  }

  class SSA extends SS_Clear {
    case class AA() extends AALike
  }
  object SSA extends SSA {}
}
```

This will compile without any error. However the shortcut stops here, if the function definition `def AA` is parameterized, then neither the inner case class nor inner object is capable of overriding it: the `apply` function of the inner object doesn't automatically expand to a method of its outer class:

```
  trait SS_Parameterised extends SS {
    def AA(ii: Int): AnyRef
  }

  class SSB extends SS_Parameterised {
    case class AA(ii: Int) extends AALike
  }
  object SSB extends SSB {}
```

This gives an error:

```
class SSB needs to be abstract, since method AA in trait
SS_Parameterised of type (ii: Int)AnyRef is not defined
    class SSB extends SS_Parameterised {
```

My question is, is there a shortcut in this case? Why is the Scala compiler is designed to link case 1 but not case 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found 2 ways of doing this

**Method 1**: overriden by case class:

```
  trait SS_Parameterised {
    type AA <: AALike
    def AA: Int => AnyRef
  }
```

**Method 2**: overriden by implicit class:

```
  trait SS_Parameterised {
    type AA <: AALike
    implicit def AA(ii: Int): AnyRef
  }

  class SSB extends SS_Parameterised {
    implicit class AA(ii: Int) extends AALike
  }
```

End of story :) One case class overriding 2 declarations? No problem.

(Method 2 works as scala internally generates an implicit function for every implicit class)

Answer (score 4):

It's not particularly designed at all; or, it is, but not in the way you seem to think. You aren't overriding `def AA()` with a method that constructs `AA`, you are overriding it with the `object AA` itself. Notice

```
trait T {
   type I <: AnyRef
   def I(): AnyRef
}
object O extends T {
   case class I(val i: Int)
}
```

This works fine.

```
> (O: T).I()
I
> (O: T).I().getClass
class O$I$
> O.I(5)
I(5)
> O.I(5).getClass
class O$I
```

The salient design choices are "`object`s can override no-param `def`s" (and so can `val`s, `var`s and, of course, no-param `def`s) and "`case class`es automatically generate `object`s". "Inner `case class`es override methods of the same name in their outer class with their constructors," is not one of Scala's rules. `object O` contains a `case class I` and an `object I`, and the abstract `def I(): AnyRef` is overridden to return said `object I`. The contents of `object I` don't matter, because `def I()` only has to return an `AnyRef`, which means no restrictions are imposed. It makes perfect sense that

```
trait U {
   type I <: AnyRef
   def I(i: Int): AnyRef
}
object P extends U {
   case class I(i: Int)
}
```

fails, then. `object P` contains a `case class I` and an associated `object I`, but it also needs a `def I(i: Int): AnyRef`, which it lacks.

Comment: agreed but in this case def I(i: Int) can't be defined anymore.
This is a good answer but let's see if a scala compiler designer can clarify this in a few days.

Comment: @tribbloid What does "`def I(i: Int)` can't be defined anymore" mean? In what "case"? I can add a `def I(i: Int): AnyRef = java.lang.Integer.valueOf(i)` or whatever to both `object O` and `object P` and have them both compile.

Comment: yes you are right, just did a quick experiment and turns out that the new function definition is possible. Accepted as canonical answer

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing it is simply related to the role `apply` plays in case classes. See [Case Class default apply method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34533539/case-class-default-apply-method)
`SSA` satisfies `SS_Clear.AA` via companion object of `SSA` (`SSA.apply`).

When you add a parameter to the method you no longer have the 0-parameter `apply` method to fulfill that role.